# Can a Plone viewlet be made to appear on one page or folder only?

Tags: plone, viewlets

Plone's viewlets appear to be site-wide by default. How can I make a viewlet only appear on a certain page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done with Theme Interface in Plone. Check this documentation:

http://plone.org/documentation/manual/theme-reference/buildingblocks/components/themespecific

If u created your Theme / viewlet with a paster template, all should be in place and ready to use.

Comment: The link above seems not reachable. You might want to see http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/views/viewlets.html#conditionally-rendering-viewlets for reference.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to theme-specific viewlets, mentioned by @user276028, you can create browserlayers for non-theme viewlets:

Example taken from [collective.atimage.transformtoolbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.atimage.transformtoolbar):

1. Create a **browserlayer** (you can create them with paster localcommand `addcontent browserlayer`):

   - Add an [interface for the layer](http://dev.plone.org/collective/browser/collective.atimage.transformtoolbar/trunk/collective/atimage/transformtoolbar/interfaces.py).
   - Create a [browserlayer.xml](http://dev.plone.org/collective/browser/collective.atimage.transformtoolbar/trunk/collective/atimage/transformtoolbar/profiles/default/browserlayer.xml) file GenericSetup to register it as a layer.
2. Use the layer in viewlet registration:

   - Edit your viewlet registration in configure.zcml with a [layer attribute](http://dev.plone.org/collective/browser/collective.atimage.transformtoolbar/trunk/collective/atimage/transformtoolbar/browser/configure.zcml#L37) pointing to your interface.

In the configure.zcml linked file you can also see how to show the viewlet just for some content types (`for` property) and just for default view of that content type (`view` property).

Any other case, I think you should decide when to show/hide your viewlet code or template, like in the [available](http://dev.plone.org/collective/browser/collective.atimage.transformtoolbar/trunk/collective/atimage/transformtoolbar/browser/viewlets.py#L12) method.